# My Threading design is ok or not?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I am new in threading and I am a junior developer :) So I guess there are many mistakes. My scenario is this:

- look to DataBase if threre are datas witch are will be sended take those datas
- Add this datas to Queue
- if queue not empty dequeue next mesaj and send it
- and wait 10 seconds a msj from another thread,
- if the msj came stop to waiting and pass to next msg in queue
- if the msj didnt came try send-wait it 10seconds 2 times again
- if still there is no msg pass to next msg until msgs finished.
- then again look to database for msgs

I am trying to do this like this:

```
    private Thread ReceiveThread;
    private Thread SendThread;
    internal static Thread ServiceThread;
```

this 3 threads

```
    ReceiveThread = new Thread(ReceiveTask);
    ReceiveThread.Start();
    ServiceThread = new Thread(SerAutoThread.SendServiceMsg);
    ServiceThread.Start();
    SendThread = new Thread(SendTask);
    SendThread.Start();
```

..

```
 class SerAutoThread
    {
    internal static object[] NextService;
    public static readonly object _locker = new object();
    internal static Queue<object[]> Services;
    internal static int sendingTime = 0;
    private static DatabaseFirebird DB;
    internal static void SendServiceMsg()
    {
        DB = new DatabaseFirebird();
        DB.Open(ConnectionStr);
        Services = new Queue<object[]>();
        while (true)
        {
            if (Services.Count != 0)
            {
                SetNextSerAndSend();
            }
            else
            {
                CheckAndSetServices();
            }
        }
    }


     private static void SetNextSerAndSend()
    {
        NextService = Services.Dequeue();
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                if (sendingTime == TRANSMITTED)
                {
                   //pass to next msg
                   sendingTime = 0;
                   j = NEXTMSG;
                }
                else if (sendingTime < 3)
                {
                    sendingTime++;
                    Byte[] data = SetNextPckage();
                    DeviceManager.MessageSendQueue.PostItem(new SendMessage("UDPCmd",
                NextService[(int)NextMsg.DeviceId].ToString(), 
                data, data.Length));
                    MyDebug.WriteLine("Sended...");
                    lock (_locker)
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(_locker, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    // pass to next msg
                    j = NEXTMSG;
                }
            }

    }
}
```

..

```
private void ReceiveTask()
        {
            ReceiveMessage receiveMsg;
            while (true)
            {
                receiveMsg = Com.MessageReceiveQueue.GetItem(-1);
                SerAutoThread.sendingTime
                        = SerAutoThread.TRANSMITTED;
                    lock (SerAutoThread._locker)
                    {
                        Monitor.Pulse(SerAutoThread._locker);
                    }

            }
        }
```

...

```
 private void SendTask()
        {
            SendMessage msg;
            while (true)
            {
                msg = MessageSendQueue.GetItem(-1);
                String rtrn = PushData(msg);
            }

        }
```

is it thread safe or not.  I'm not sure if something is wrong with the design or I'm doing something wrong elsewhere ?
Thanks...

Comment: You may take a look to the TPL, Reactive Extensions or TPL-Dataflow. There you find safe ways to this. Think about exception handling etc. Take a look at this libraries and use them to solve your problem.

Comment: I think this belongs more in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you missed some corner cases where you can get a race condition. For example, the `SerAutoThread` could write a package to the `MessageSendQueue`, which is immediately acknowledged before `SerAutoThread` even starts waiting (unlikely but possible). This will only cause an unintended delay and not malfunction though.

However, another corner case is if `ReceiveTask` receives an acknowledgement after `SerAutoThread` already gave up waiting and already sent the next message. In that case, `SerAutoThread` would think that `ReceiveTask` just acknowledged the new message when it really acknowledged the previous one. You'll probably need to give IDs to your messages to prevent this from happening, so that you can tell exactly which message is being acknowledged.

Edit: Based on your comment I'm looking at the code again with an eye for whether there is a risk of deadlock or livelock. I'll assume that your `MessageSendQueue` and `MessageReceiveQueue` are instances of blocking producer-consumer style queues, similar to [this one](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/492902-inter-thread-message-queue-c) based on the method names and parameters. I'll also assume that the threads were not killed due to exceptions, because (I sincerely hope) you would have noticed that.

Let's start with the `SendThread` because it is the easiest to analyze; There is basically nothing that can go wrong here from a threading perspective, although it would be nice to have a way to cleanly shut the thing down. As long as stuff is posted into the queue (and `PushData` doesn't somehow jam up), this thread will eventually send it.

`ReceiveThread` follows the same (good, safe) pattern of consuming items from a queue, but it also communicates with the `ServiceThread` through a shared variable and a monitor - not so safe and very low-level. Assuming that we're seeing all references to the `_locker` object, there is no risk of deadlock here because there is no code that ever waits for anything else while holding the `_locker` lock. In summary, this thread will also continue to do its thing as long as messages are available in the queue.

However, setting `sendingTime` like you do is a data race and might cause unintended behaviour in the `ServiceThread`. That's because the change to `sendingTime` might occur at any time, e.g. between the check `if(sendingTime < 3)` and the increment on the next line, leaving you with TRANSMITTED+1. There are also other wacky things that could happen. When you access the same variable from two threads, you always need to make sure that there is proper synchronization in place.

But can this cause `ServiceThread` to lock up? Assuming that `2 < NEXTMSG < int.MaxValue`, I don't really see how. The loop in `SetNextSerAndSend()` will run at most four times before discarding the current `Service`, and wait at most 10 seconds per run, so it should always be moving forward.

It seems that we can still get into a situation where nothing useful can happen anymore though. If sendingTime ever becomes a value that is neither below 3 nor TRANSMITTED, it doesn't seem to be set anymore. The loop in `SetNextSerAndSend()` will always execute the else-branch and skip to the next message immediately. It appears to me that `sendingTime` would have to be reset to 0 in the else-branch as well to prevent this. Note that this would allow the sending to move forward again, but your program won't be thread-safe until you synchronize all accesses to `sendingTime`.

Comment: actualy I give id to my msgs. And this is not my entire code(for understandable).when I run the app this works fine, yesterday just ones my Database managment system(Firebird) loked. then I stopped my app, stopped firebird server then started again and run my app again. now it is ok again. I am not using threads with deeply unerstanding. So i am worried about thread safe. Is it posible the thread locked firebird ?

Comment: I extended my answer quite a bit - sorry if it's quite verbose but I was writing at the same time as trying to analyze your code, plus I'm tired. However, I might have actually found out how your code can livelock (i.e. continue running without deadlock but without ever doing anything useful anymore).